# Capybara unable to find field "search"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I tried setting the id in various parts of the form, as well as wrapping the form in a div with id set to `search`. The result is always the same.

## spec/features/02_post_spec.rb

```
  scenario 'search for post title' do
    fill_post_form(post3)
    fill_in "search", with: post3.title
    click_button("Search")

    expect(page).to_not have_content(post1.title)
    expect(page).to_not have_content(post2.title)
    expect(page).to have_content(post3.title)
  end
```

## spec/spec_helper.rb

```
def fill_post_form(post)
  visit new_post_path
  fill_in 'Title', with: post.title
  fill_in 'Body', with: post.body
  click_button 'Create Post'
end
```

This will `redirect_to post_path(post)`

## views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, method: :get, class: "block") do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", id: "search" %>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Capybara output

```
 Failure/Error: fill_in "search", with: post3.title

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "search"
```

Comment: Have a look at the raw html of the form on your page... it is likely that he field is called something ever-so-slightly different. If you're trying based on id, then you probably also want `fill_in '#search'` or similar.

Comment: @TarynEast  `fill_in` searches by name, id, or associated label text of the input element to be filled in - it does not accept CSS selectors so it would be `fill_in 'search', ...` not #search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `fill_in "search", with: post3.title` you're using should work, assuming you are on the page rendering the shown partial, and the output of that partial is actually visible on the page (not hidden via CSS).  Your scenario doesn't show visiting an actual page, and you don't show what `fill_post_form` is doing so it's tough to know exactly what is going wrong.  First step would be to do something like

```
fill_post_form(post3) # already in your tests
sleep 2 # wait a few seconds to make sure above method has completed whatever actions it does
puts page.html  # output the current page and take a look to see if your 'search' element is actually on the page
```

Comment: You were right. It was as simple as being on the wrong page. I've been staring at the screen for too long. Thank you.

Comment: @n.milsht you're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer, if it helped you, so the question gets marked as answered